# Names of foreign key constraints changed in mysql dump

Tags: mysql, sql

Whenever i make a database backup using this command:

```
mysqldump --all-databases
```

It will change all the foreign key constraints names. We are using Syfmony2 framework with doctrine migrations. It looks like mysql apllies a naming strategy for foreign keys. I wonder if it's possible too keep the foreign key constraints names the same.

Any ideas?

For example: on the constraint for user is FK_B2D59BB34A8BC2 In the backup it says User_ibfk_1

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide an example of such a change?

Comment: For example: on the constraint for user is FK_B2D59BB34A8BC2 In the backup it says User_ibfk_1